# How to correctly set up this layout

Tags: android, xml

I have this as part of a layout

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/home_btn"
    style="@style/Home_Button">

    <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/a"
        android:text="@string/centres"/>

    <ImageView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/a"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_home_btn"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I need the TextView to be centered in the RelativeLayout, and the ImageView to be above the TextView, with a set dp offset (e.g. a 10dp gap between the image and the text)

I've tried various different methods and nothings worked so far. How can I correctly get this to work?

Oh, here's the style

```
<style name="Home_Button_NL">

    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/home_button</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginTop">@dimen/padding_tiny</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of `android:drawableLeft/Right/Top/Bottom` to position an Image to the TextView. Furthermore you can use some padding between the TextView and the drawable with `android:drawablePadding=""`

Use it like this:

```
<TextView 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:gravity="center"

    android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_home_btn"
    android:drawablePadding="10dp"

    android:id="@+id/a"
    android:text="@string/centres"/>
```

This way you only have to position one View in the center of the RelativeLayout.

Note that you can't scale your Image this way. I suggest this because there is no scaling in your setup.

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:center_horizontal = "true"` and `alignParentBottom = "true"`in your TextView

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/home_btn"
    style="@style/Home_Button">

    <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/a"
        android:text="@string/centres"
        android:centerInParent="true"   // center the textview in it's parent
     "/>

    <ImageView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/a"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_home_btn"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" // center imageview horizontally
        android:layout_marginTop="YOUR MARGIN HERE"
     />
</RelativeLayout>
```

This may help !

Comment: I've actually previously tried that, I thought it would work, but it centers both elements so there's equal distance above the image as there is below the text

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
android:paddingBottom="10dp"
```